# magento 2 Deepest Category product list page gives Error 500. Which files to inspect?

Tags: magento2, category, catalog, category-products, category-view

The site I'm working on the lowest category page (suppose to be list view) give the error 500.
I'm not quite remember file I edited.
search result also return the same error. 
Which files should I look into to fix the error?

Thanks.

> this is the error from debug.log  [2019-02-22 06:36:35] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://dev.siig.com/it-products/video-display/display-adapters/usb-2-0.html","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
>   [2019-02-22 06:37:41] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?  500 is a server error which may occur either due to bad code or server misconfiguration

Comment: I tried clear the cache but didn't help. If it's bad code, which file should I look into. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the file that was causing the issue.
it was the `app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml`
that was containing some bad codes...